# Compress code for multiple events in javascript

Tags: javascript

Can this be done in any better way or must i type "object.event = function" for all?

```
namn1.onfocus = clearField;
foretag1.onfocus = clearField;
telefon1.onfocus = clearField;
hemsida1.onfocus = clearField;
meddelande1.onfocus = clearField;
namn2.onfocus = clearField;
foretag2.onfocus = clearField;
telefon2.onfocus = clearField;
hemsida2.onfocus = clearField;
meddelande2.onfocus = clearField;

namn1.onblur = restoreField;
foretag1.onblur = restoreField;
telefon1.onblur = restoreField;
hemsida1.onblur = restoreField;
meddelande1.onblur = restoreField;    
namn2.onblur = restoreField;
foretag2.onblur = restoreField;
telefon2.onblur = restoreField;
hemsida2.onblur = restoreField;
meddelande2.onblur = restoreField;
```

Comment: no jquery is not an option :)

Comment: Well there goes my answer. :)

Comment: i also don't want to add classes, I want to work with id's...

Comment: Thanks for all comments!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this, but it's not that much better:

```
var fields = [
    namn1, foretag1, telefon1, hemsida1, meddelande1,
    namn2, foretag2, telefon2, hemsida2, meddelande2
];

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].onfocus = clearField;
    fields[i].onblur = restoreField;
}
```

jQuery would give you more control, but I don't know if you want to use it.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it. Could also make it a function that takes in an array of objects

Answer (score 0):

```
var elements = [namn1, foretag1, telefon1, hemsida1, meddelande1, namn2, foretag2, telefon2, hemsida2, meddelande2];
for (var i in elements) {
    elements[i].onfocus = clearField;
    elements[i].onblur = restoreField;
}
```

This could be made even more concise if these elements could be accessible by ID — then, one could halve the array by getting the each pair of elements.

Comment: You should not use `for ... in` to iterate over the items in an array. It is meant to iterate over the properties of an object, and the result may not be what you expect. Use an indexed `for` loop instead.

Comment: @Sean, [it's already there](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/javascript-for-in-with-arrays) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
[namn1, foretag1, telefon1, hemsida1, meddelande1,
 namn2, foretag2, telefon2, hemsida2, meddelande2].forEach(function(e) {
  e.onfocus = clearField;
  e.onblur = restoreField;
});
```

Comment: Nice.  The only minor nit is that it won't work in IE8 or lower, but who uses that anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Just a tiny variation on Sean's answer because I like this method of creating arrays.

```
var fields = "namn1 foretag1 telefon1 hemsida1 meddeland1 namn2 foretag2 telefon2 hemsida2 meddelande2".split(" ");

for(i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
   fields[i].onfocus = clearField;
   fields[i].onblur = restoreField;
}
```